# What measure to use to compare stratified and non stratified Cox proportional hazards in R

Tags: r, cox-model, likelihood-ratio, proportional-hazards, wald-test

I am doing past papers studying for an exam on medical statistics and am unsure about one of the questions. The question reads as follows:

"Consider now a second model where we stratify by sex instead of including it
as a factor in the model. State which of the five provided measures of model fit and performance (“Concordance”, “Rsquare”, “Likelihood ratio test”, “Wald test”, and “Score (logrank) test”) might be used to compare the two models, and explain why this
is, and why the others are inappropriate."

I understand why $R^2$ likelihood-ratio test would be inappropriate as it is calculated in way that uses the log-likelihood (and this is a partial likelihood), and why concordance isn't appropriate as the number of ties are affected by the stratification and ties are penalized in stratification, but I am not too sure about the Wald Test and the logrank test. Any help on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated (or further insight on why a likelihood test is inappropriate may be interesting).

```
    Call: coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + sex, data = lung)
    n= 227, number of events= 164
    (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
    coef exp(coef) se(coef) z Pr(>|z|)
    ph.ecog 0.4875 1.6282 0.1122 4.344 1.4e-05 ***
    sex -0.5530 0.5752 0.1676 -3.300 0.000967 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes: 0 *** 0.001 ** 0.01 * 0.05 . 0.1 1
    exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
    ph.ecog 1.6282 0.6142 1.3067 2.0288
    sex 0.5752 1.7384 0.4142 0.7989
    Concordance= 0.642 (se = 0.025 )
    Rsquare= 0.12 (max possible= 0.999 )
    Likelihood ratio test= 29.05 on 2 df, p=5e-07
    Wald test = 28.96 on 2 df, p=5e-07
    Score (logrank) test = 29.41 on 2 df, p=4e-07
```

Comment: You say: "concordance isn't appropriate as the number of ties are affected by the stratification..."  If the goal is to "compare the two models," aren't you trying to see which of the models does the best at distinguishing predicted and observed orders of events? Isn't that precisely what concordance estimates?

Comment: This is the quote from my lecture notes: "Note also that ties are penalized [in concordance], and that large numbers of ties are inevitable if we have a purely factorial design. They may also be disproportionately affected by stratification."

Comment: The exam question is posed in terms of comparing 2 different models on the same data set. Ties might "penalize" a concordance estimate, but the 2 models would be penalized similarly on that account as they have the same ties in times. It might be best to start by considering the simpler situation in which there are no ties. That's how presentations of survival modeling typically start, to avoid the complications of how to deal with ties. In that simpler situation, how would you answer the question?

Comment: If there are no ties between the data, then I don't believe concordance would be effected by stratification and that would be the best evaluation metric to choose. That makes a lot of sense thank you so much for your help!